# Do guitar tablature websites or websites that provide sheet music have to pay royalties to songs authors?

Tags: copyright, music

Do websites that provide guitar tablature or musical notes of popular songs have to pay royalties to song authors or record labels ?

I'm talking about websites like:

- https://www.songsterr.com/
- https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/
- https://synthesiagame.com/

If one of these websites provides tablatures for my song, without my permission, can I sue them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do. Generally they don't pay royalties on individual songs, they are more likely to contract for a specific collection of songs or artists, or even an entire label. 
[Here's what Synthesia](https://synthesiagame.com/about) says about this on their site.
[Songsterr](https://www.songsterr.com/a/wa/terms) explains this in their terms of service.

> Songsterr is backed by U.S.-based Guitar Tabs LLC and it is 100% legal. We have great relationships with music publishers, all of the content provided through our Service is licensed, and we pay a percentage of our revenue as royalties to support music creators.

If you find your own work being distributed you could sue, but these services generally provide a way to report such incidents, and you would probably want to start there rather than going directly to court.